# R- How to conduct two-sample t-test with two different survey designs

Tags: r, survey, t-test

I want to perform a two-sample (welch's) t-test on the equality of two means, one of which is obtained using simple random sampling (`srsmean`), and the other which is calculated using survey weighting with the survey package (`mean_weighted`). I also conduct a t-test between `mean_weighted` and the mean obtained when weighting and stratification are both implemented in the survey design (`mean_strat`).

I know there is a `svyttest()` function, however, as far as I can tell, this function only tests the means of two samples *within* one survey design, not means obtained with different survey designs.

I also tried using rnorm to create fictional samples eg `c(rnorm(9710, mean = 156958.8, sd = 364368))`, but the problem with this approach is that in complex sampling methods like stratification, the *effective* n is usually smaller than the *nominal* n, and so I am unsure what to put as n. Additionally, this method feels a bit contrived, as I would be fitting the data to a particular type of distribution.

Finally, I tried writing out the equation for a t-statistic myself, however, in calculating the "standard error of the difference of means" involving a complex survey design, I also run into problems related to the "effective sample size."

Is there another approach that would work for both the t-test between `srsmean, mean_weighted` AND the t-test between `mean_weighted, mean_strat`?

```
library(survey)

wel <- c(68008.19, 128504.61,  21347.69,
         33272.95,  61828.96,  32764.44,
         92545.62,  58431.89,  95596.82,
         117734.27)
rmul <- c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
          20, 20, 20)
strat <- c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102)


survey.data <- data.frame(wel, rmul, strat)

srsmean <- mean(survey.data$wel)

survey_weighted <- svydesign(data = survey.data,
                             ids = ~wel, 
                             weights = ~rmul, 
                             nest = TRUE)

mean_weighted <- svymean(~wel, survey_weighted)

survey_strat <- survey_strat <- svydesign(data = surveydata, 
                                          ids= ~wel, 
                                          weights = ~rmul, 
                                          strata = ~strat, 
                                          nest = TRUE)
mean_strat <- svymean(~wel, survey_strat)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'm confused about the purpose of a t-test between your `mean_weighted` and `mean_strat` since the difference between those coefficients will always be zero?  i might compare the simple random sample against the complex design like this?

```
library(survey)

wel <- c(68008.19, 128504.61,  21347.69,
         33272.95,  61828.96,  32764.44,
         92545.62,  58431.89,  95596.82,
         117734.27)
rmul <- c(16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16,
          20, 20, 20)
strat <- c(101, 101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 102, 102)

survey.data <- data.frame(wel, rmul, strat)

survey_unweighted <- svydesign(data = survey.data,
                             ids = ~1)

mean_unweighted <- svymean(~wel, survey_unweighted)

survey_strat <- survey_strat <- svydesign(data = survey.data, 
                                          ids= ~wel, 
                                          weights = ~rmul, 
                                          strata = ~strat, 
                                          nest = TRUE)
mean_strat <- svymean(~wel, survey_strat)


coef_one <- coef( mean_unweighted )
coef_two <- coef( mean_strat )
se_one <- SE( mean_unweighted )
se_two <- SE( mean_strat )

t_statistic <- abs( coef_one - coef_two ) / sqrt ( se_one ^2 + se_two ^2 )
p_value <- ( 1 - pnorm( abs( coef_one - coef_two ) / sqrt( se_one ^2 + se_two ^2 ) ) ) * 2
sig_diff <- ifelse( 1 - pnorm( abs( coef_one - coef_two ) / sqrt( se_one ^2 + se_two ^2 ) ) < 0.025 , "*" , "" )
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is extremely helpful. And your confusion is warranted: the code is for an econometrics educational resource to demonstrate how weighting and complex sampling affect the means/variances (I will go on to F-test the variances). It might seem banal to test the difference of means between two survey designs that are weighted the same, but it is for the purpose of demonstration (but now that I am thinking about this more, I may leave it out...)